# How to replace backslash in Dataweave Mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Hi like to replace backslash with an empty character.

My Payload is

```
{
"id" : 1234567,
"requestDate" : "2021/02/02",
"responseXML" : "<DRIVEResponse ResponseDateTime=\"2/15/2021 10:09:10 AM\" TimeZone=\"EST\">",
}
```

I tried some ways but it seems nothing is working am not sure what is the mistake i am doing .

```
payload.responseXML replace "\"  with ""
```

My Expected response is

```
<DRIVEResponse ResponseDateTime="2/15/2021 10:09:10 AM" TimeZone="EST">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the mistake is trying to remove the backlash character (`\`). It is the JSON escape character that is needed to escape the double quote character inside a JSON string. Note that responseXML contains as its value a string that contains an XML value. XML uses quotes around attribute values. The only way to represent those in a JSON string is to escape. That's the expected behavior as defined by JSON standards. It should be fine unless you are processing it with a non compliant JSON parser. If at some point you need to evaluate that string as an XML, the resulting XML will not have a backlash.

For example I will use your input data an read responseXML. Note however that the XML is not well formed because it lacks a closing tag. I just added a forward slash (`/`) to close the tag:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
read(payload.responseXML,"application/xml")
```

Input payload:

```
{
"id" : 1234567,
"requestDate" : "2021/02/02",
"responseXML" : "<DRIVEResponse ResponseDateTime=\"2/15/2021 10:09:10 AM\" TimeZone=\"EST\" />"
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<DRIVEResponse ResponseDateTime="2/15/2021 10:09:10 AM" TimeZone="EST"/>
```

There is actually an alternative. If you can control the generation of the XML you could use single quotes. The XML standard allows for both single quotes or double quotes. I don't recommend to do this though. It looks like it is for hiding an issue in some other component. It feels like a bad practice to me.

Answer (score 1):

That is how your **"** are escaped within a string that is surrounded by **""**.

`\"` is rendered as **"** in the eventual string. See the screengrab below and notice how `\"` does not get replaced while ***"*** does get replaced in the sentence.

[image]